# Convert many:many response into single objects

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-7

I have defined a `users` table, a `roles` table and a `user_role` pivot in my database. The model for the `user` is as follows:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    //... Fields defined here

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_role');
    }
}
```

Inside the role model, I have this also:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    //... Fields defined here
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_role');
    }
}
```

Now here lies the problem.
When I run the following in the API routes (relatively crude)

```php
$user_roles = \App\Models\User::with('roles')->get();
```

I get a list of all the users, with each array having an internal array of all the roles. I will like the results such that each user will have one role and if there are multiple roles, I duplicate the user with this new role.

How is this achieved? Thanks in advance for the assistance

Comment: I would revert the operation and run `\App\Models\Role::with('users')->get()`; it gives you unique roles with all the users for that role.

Comment: In that case, I'll also prefer to have the workouts duplicated for every user...

Comment: Loop over the results and create your desired structure

Comment: @brombeer, that was my first approach also. Thanks for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like `flatMap`:

```
$user_roles = \App\Models\User::with('roles')->get()
   ->flatMap(function ($user) {
      if ($user->roles->isEmpty()) { return $user; }
      return $user->roles->map(function ($role) use ($user) { 
            $newUser = clone $user;
            $newUser->roles = $role;
            return $newUser;
      });
   });
```

An alternative is to use a join instead of an eloquent relationship e.g.:

```
$user_roles = DB::table('users')
    ->join('user_role', 'user_role.user_id', 'user.id')
    ->join('roles', 'user_role,role_id', 'roles.id')
    ->selectRaw('users.*, roles.*')->get();
```

This should result in a result of users and roles combined in one object.

Comment: I tried the first option and it worked well. The second one worked also but it seemed to take a noticeably longer time (this was not benchmarked properly, so users beware).